# How to create table from SELECT statement in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to CREATE table from another table 
I tried below code

```
CREATE TABLE AS tbl_01
As
SELECT a.col1 c1, a.col2 c2, MAX(a.col3 c3)
FROM tbl a
WHERE flag= 2
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

This query run, but When I am going to expand column in datatabse explorer it gives error `Conversion from type DBNULL to type Integer is not valid`

Comment: Why have you added `mysql` tag when you are working on `oracle` database? Also, could you please describe the table `tbl` using `desc tbl`. And **why do you want to create the table at first place when you already have the data in another table?**

Comment: @LalitKumarB- because I want to create new table with given condition.

Comment: You could always select the data with given condition. Why do you need another table? Also, please provide the requested details.

Comment: @LalitKumarB- Because I want to store and use same selected column with condition to create next table. I did not get how I use this 'desc tbl' ?? please explain

Comment: The query won't run and thus will not create a table. `MAX(a.col3 c3)` is invalid SQL. The error message indicates a problem with the *tool* you are using, not with your query or the table itself.

Comment: Rigth same issue , but query is different. expanding column means when we view this table in database explorer , then it reflect error `conversion from DBNull to Interger is not valid`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- I tried to keep alias to outside braces also, but not works.If I go with only `select `statement then query works fine, But I want to create table with same data

Comment: Again: this is a problem with the _tool_ you are using. Which SQL client is that? And what data type is `tbl.col3`?

Comment: No Not Like this. anyways I got my solution. And there no any problem in SQL client. Its all right

Answer (score 11):

Put alias outside braces in max function and try. Also you use `as` twice. COrrected that.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_01
As
SELECT a.col1 c1, a.col2 c2, MAX(a.col3) c3
FROM tbl a
WHERE flag= 2
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: Twice `AS` is by mistake. I tried to give alise name outside braces, But still facing same error when expand column `Conversion from DBNull to Interger is not valid`

Comment: @Utsav- when I go with only select statement , then it works fine. Then how to create table with this data?