# copy some rows from one table to another new table

Tags: sql

I have several thousands of the records and in  a few hundred lines columns that are empty, I would like to save these rows in another table

i have this table :

```
id | name  | lati      |  longi    
1  | name1 | 47.482539 | 6.778554    
2  | name2 | (empty)   |  (empty)           
3  | name3 | 50.075055 | 1.97328    
4  | name4 | 46.333055 | 7.99571    
5  | name5 | (empty)  |  (empty)
```

I would like in new table to have this

```
id | name  | lati     |  longi
1  | name2 | (empty)  |  (empty) 
1  | name5 | (empty)  |  (empty)
```

what sql command can allow me to do this

thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-generation site. We expect you to show some form of effort and present specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all Rdms support `CREATE TABLE SELECT`

so you can make a query like this

```
CREATE TABLE table_new AS
SELECT id , name  , lati,  longi
FROM Table_olD WHERE lati IS NULL ANd longi IS NULL
```

**SQL Server** uses `SELECT INTO table_name` see [How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008)

The following

**MySQL** uses  `CREATE tABLe As SELECT` [MySQL Create Table as SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715580/mysql-create-table-as-select)

**Oracle** also usese `CREATE TABLE AS SELCT` [How to create table from SELECT statement in oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772866/how-to-create-table-from-select-statement-in-oracle-11g)

**Postgres** uses also `CREATE TABLe AS SELECT` [Postgres - CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953450/postgres-create-table-from-select)

**sqlite**  also follows the schema `CREATE TABLe AS SELRCT` [Copy table structure to new table in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730390/copy-table-structure-to-new-table-in-sqlite3)

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: thank you nbk, this is the right request to do the job.